# Rails 5 redirect_back not behaving as expected locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Ive recently upgraded an application to Rails 5 and subsequently updated all references to `redirect_to :back`, to `redirect_back`.

This seems to be behaving as expected in production, when running the app locally, it redirects to the url of the last image that was rendered on the page. While this is not really an issue I wondered if anyone has encountered anything similar and has any solutions?

Comment: Having this issue as well...

Answer (score 0):

Install plun-in "No Referer Switch" in Chrome Browser, the redirect_back method will be implemented as you expected.

I got the same problem when i use the method redirect_back, and i find the reason in the source code

```
#source code in rails
def redirect_back(fallback_location:, **args)
  if referer = request.headers["Referer"]
    redirect_to referer, **args
  else
    redirect_to fallback_location, **args
  end
end
```

according to the source code, if the request.header["Referer"] exists, the page will return to the last image regardless the value of fallback_location.

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
redirect_back(fallback_location: users_path)
```

I use chrome browser, the code above will return some result, you can debug it. I find a chrome plugin which is called "no referer switch" and enable it, the plugin can make the referer in http head inactive, so redirect_back method will implemented as we expected.